# Unable to copy warfile from agent folder to Tomcat folder in AzureDevops using command line script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to copy a war file from my localhost to a Tomcat web apps folder using command line script in Azure DevOps. My release is getting success but the war file is not getting copying to the destination folder. How to fix this issue?

Path folder mentioned below

[image]

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: No it is not resolved I am getting error cmd.exe exited with code 1 like that error it is showing

Comment: Hi @nitesh, I have updated the answer, check the update1, we need to confirm that the file exists, if not, we will get the error  "cmd.exe exited with code 1"

Comment: i am sharing the error log which I am getting yeah I am using my laptop as a local host                               

2021-01-15T02:50:04.8513132Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\a5ed2a04-cb0c-482e-ae1d-600ce2f3e39d.cmd""
2021-01-15T02:50:04.8736236Z The system cannot find the path specified.
2021-01-15T02:50:04.8743514Z The system cannot find the file specified.
2021-01-15T02:50:04.9630720Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
2021-01-15T02:50:05.0343894Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script

Comment: Hi @nitesh, Did you see my latest news? Could you check if the file is in the path provided in cmd? We need to ensure the file that the file exists, I can get the same error if I delete the test file

Comment: HI, @Vito Liu-MSFT I checked in the command line by giving the directory the folder is working fine but in azure DevOps when I am trying to release at that time the above log file is generated with the error. can you mention to me what is this test file I didn't come accross it

Comment: Hi, @VitoLiu-MSFT if possible I will connect with you on skype or TeamViewer regarding this issue I am able to work in the command line but in azure DevOps, it is not working getting the error last 2 days I struck here error it is getting ::: 2021-01-15T05:01:43.8176571Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

Comment: Hi @nitesh, We could contact with TeamViewer. In addition, could you open the file webapp.war directory and run the release pipeline again? Check to see if the file is automatically deleted while the pipeline is running.

Comment: Hi @nitesh, I have update the answer, please check the update2, if you still occur this issue, we could connect on TeamViewer. In addition, you could also share some screenshot here, such as local result, release definition Agent pool. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT thank you for the update I will try it and share the update according to it

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT Thank you very much it worked and the issue is resolved

Comment: Hi @nitesh, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Done.. @Vito Liu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you shared `echo cd E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.41\webapps` just print `cd E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.41\webapps`, check the pic below. We could refer to this [doc](https://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Files-in-Command-Prompt) for more details.

[image]

We could copy the file via below cmd. Add task `Command line` and enter below script

```
cd {file path}
copy {file name} {target path}
```

According to the screenshot you shared, you could try below script

```
cd C:\agent\_work\r1\a\_nitesh482.Devops\warfile\webapp\target
copy webapp.war E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.41\webapps
```

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

If the file does not exist, we will get the message: *The system cannot find the file specified*. and error message: *[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'*

[image]

**Update2**

Please ensure that you are using self-hosted agent instead of hosted agent. If you are using hosted agent, we will get the error message, check the pic below.

Self-hosted agent:

[image]

Hosted agent:

[image]